# The store provider factory type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory' does not implement the IServiceProvider interface

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

Using .NET 4.8 and Oracle 21c with Visual Studio 2022. I have installed the Oracle data tools and added sections to machine.config as specified here https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/odpnt/InstallConfig.html#GUID-ECDA2778-4835-417C-B81A-E0E1103B5B52. Also tried to use OraProvCfg to configure machine.conig and get "ERROR: Unable to find some required types."

Answer (score 3):

you have to install package of (oracle.ManagedDataAccess) that implement the required interface (IserviceProvider),
i have tried Versions:

- 21.6.1
- 21.5.0
- 21.4.0

but its not worked successfully .

version **19.15.1** working good because it implement the interface .